Error processing file n.mp4: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'
i am trying to convert and compress the given videos to the given video format but getting the following error:
Error processing file n.mp4: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'.
i don't know why the function convert_video_to_video is taking compression_percentage as a list.
following is my django view:
import os
import io
import zipfile
import re
import logging
import subprocess
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
import boto3
from moviepy.video.fx import all as vfx
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CompressVideoView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.debug("Received video conversion request")

        files = request.FILES.getlist('files')
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        bucket_name = settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
        folder = 'videos/'

        video_formats = request.data.getlist('formats')
        screen_size = request.data.getlist('screen_size', 'no-change')
        frame_rate = request.data.getlist('frame_rate', 'no-change')
        rotate = request.data.getlist('rotate', 'no-change')
        flip = request.data.getlist('flip', 'no-change')

        subtitle = request.data.getlist('subtitle')
        copy_subtitles = request.data.getlist('copy_subtitles')
        remove_subtitles = request.data.getlist('remove_subtitles')

        volume = request.data.getlist('volume')
        fade_in = request.data.getlist('fade_in')
        fade_out = request.data.getlist('fade_out')
        remove_audio = request.data.getlist('remove_audio')

        trim_start_h = request.data.getlist('trim_start_h', 0)
        trim_start_m = request.data.getlist('trim_start_m', 0)
        trim_start_s = request.data.getlist('trim_start_s', 0)
        trim_end_h = request.data.getlist('trim_end_h', 0)
        trim_end_m = request.data.getlist('trim_end_m', 0)
        trim_end_s = request.data.getlist('trim_end_s', 0)

        # compression_percentages = request.data.getlist('compression_percentages', '60')

        compression_percentages = request.data.getlist('compression_percentages', ['60'])
        compression_percentages = [int(cp) for cp in compression_percentages]

        
        print(compression_percentages, 'compression_percentages')
        download_links = []
        success = []
        temp_files = []

        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

        def sanitize_group_name(name):
            sanitized_name = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]', '_', name)
            sanitized_name = sanitized_name[:99]
            return sanitized_name

        def parse_time(hours, minutes, seconds):
            try:
                return int(hours) * 3600 + int(minutes) * 60 + int(seconds)
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError("Invalid time format")

        def compress_video(input_path, output_path, compression_percentage, video_format):
            crf_value = max(0, min(51, 51 - int(compression_percentage)))
            unique_output_path = output_path.replace(f".{video_format}", f"_compressed.{video_format}")

            codec = 'libx264'
            audio_codec = 'aac'
            extra_args = []

            if video_format == '3gp':
                extra_args.extend(['-ar', '8000', '-ac', '1'])

            ffmpeg_command = [
                'ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', input_path,
                '-vcodec', codec,
                '-crf', str(crf_value),
                '-c:a', audio_codec,
                *extra_args,
                unique_output_path
            ]
            
            try:
                subprocess.run(ffmpeg_command, check=True)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                logger.error(f"FFmpeg error: {e}")
                raise

        def convert_video_to_video(file, video_format, compression_percentage):
            # Compression percentage should be an integer here
            compression_percentage = int(compression_percentage)  # Ensure it's an integer
            video_file_path = None
            video_file_name = None
            output_file_path = None
            temp_output_path = None
            subtitle_file_path = None
            unique_channel = sanitize_group_name(f"file_status_group_{file.name}")

            try:
                async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_add)(unique_channel, unique_channel)
                async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                    unique_channel,
                    {'type': 'send_status', 'status': 'Getting Ready'}
                )
                logger.debug(f"Starting conversion for video: {file.name}")

                with file.open('rb') as video_file:
                    video_file_path = os.path.join('/tmp', file.name)
                    with open(video_file_path, 'wb') as temp_file:
                        for chunk in video_file.chunks():
                            temp_file.write(chunk)

                if not os.path.exists(video_file_path) or os.path.getsize(video_file_path) == 0:
                    raise FileNotFoundError(f"File not found or is empty after saving: {video_file_path}")

                video_file_name = f"{file.name.rsplit('.', 1)[0]}.{video_format}"
                bucket_name,
                folder + zip_filename,
                ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'application/zip'}
            )

            zip_download_link = f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{folder + zip_filename}"
            download_links.append(zip_download_link)

        return Response({'status': 'Processing complete', 'download_links': download_links, 'success': success}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            output_file_path = os.path.join('/tmp', video_file_name)

                video = VideoFileClip(video_file_path)

                start_seconds = parse_time(trim_start_h, trim_start_m, trim_start_s)
                end_seconds = parse_time(trim_end_h, trim_end_m, trim_end_s)
                end_seconds = end_seconds if end_seconds else video.duration

                if start_seconds > end_seconds:
                    raise ValueError("Trim start time cannot be greater than trim end time")

                if end_seconds > video.duration:
                    end_seconds = video.duration

                if start_seconds > 0 or end_seconds < video.duration:
                    video = video.subclip(start_seconds, end_seconds)

                if screen_size != 'no-change':
                    width, height = map(int, screen_size.split('x'))
                    video = video.resize(newsize=(width, height))

                if frame_rate != 'no-change':
                    video = video.set_fps(float(frame_rate))

                if rotate != 'no-change':
                    video = video.rotate(float(rotate))

                if flip != 'no-change':
                    if flip.lower() == 'horizontal':
                        video = video.fx(vfx.mirror_x)
                    elif flip.lower() == 'vertical':
                        video = video.fx(vfx.mirror_y)

                if fade_in.lower() == 'true':
                    video = video.fadein(2)

                if fade_out.lower() == 'true':
                    video = video.fadeout(2)

                if video.audio is not None:
                    if volume != '100':
                        volume_factor = int(volume) / 100.0
                        video = video.volumex(volume_factor)

                    if remove_audio.lower() == 'true':
                        video = video.without_audio()

                temp_output_path = output_file_path + '.temp.mp4'
                video.write_videofile(temp_output_path, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac", threads=4, logger=None)

                final_output_path = output_file_path

                has_subtitles = False
                subtitle_file_path = os.path.join('/tmp', 'subtitles.srt')

                probe_command = [
                    'ffprobe', '-v', 'error', '-select_streams', 's:0', '-show_entries', 'stream=index', '-of', 'default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1',
                    video_file_path
                ]
                result = subprocess.run(probe_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
                if result.stdout.strip():
                    has_subtitles = True
                    extract_command = [
                        'ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', video_file_path, '-map', '0:s:0', subtitle_file_path
                    ]
                    subprocess.run(extract_command, check=True)

                ffmpeg_command = [
                    'ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', temp_output_path, '-c:v', 'libx264', '-c:a', 'aac'
                ]
                
                if video_format == '3gp':
                    ffmpeg_command.extend(['-c:a', 'libopencore_amrnb', '-ar', '8000', '-ac', '1'])

                if remove_subtitles.lower() == 'true':
                    ffmpeg_command.extend(['-sn'])

                elif copy_subtitles.lower() == 'true' and has_subtitles:
                    ffmpeg_command.extend(['-scodec', 'srt', '-map', '0'])

                elif subtitle != 'false':
                    subtitle_path = os.path.join('/tmp', 'subtitle.srt')
                    with open(subtitle_path, 'wb') as temp_subtitle:
                        for chunk in subtitle.chunks():
                            temp_subtitle.write(chunk)

                    ffmpeg_command.extend(['-vf', f"subtitles={subtitle_path}"])

                ffmpeg_command.append(final_output_path)
                subprocess.run(ffmpeg_command, check=True)

                async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                    unique_channel,
                    {'type': 'send_status', 'status': 'Converted'}
                )
                
                if compression_percentage > 0:
                    compress_video(final_output_path, final_output_path, compression_percentage, video_format)
                    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                        unique_channel,
                        {'type': 'send_status', 'status': 'Compressed'}
                    )
                
                async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                    unique_channel,
                    {'type': 'send_status', 'status': 'Uploading'}
                )

                s3.upload_file(
                    final_output_path,
                    bucket_name,
                    folder + video_file_name,
                    ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'video/mp4'}
                )

                download_link = f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{folder + video_file_name}"
                download_links.append(download_link)
                success.append({'file_name': file.name, 'status': 'Success', 'download_link': download_link})

            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error processing file {file.name}: {e}")
                success.append({'file_name': file.name, 'status': 'Failed'})
            finally:
                if temp_output_path and os.path.exists(temp_output_path):
                    os.remove(temp_output_path)
                if video_file_path and os.path.exists(video_file_path):
                    os.remove(video_file_path)
                if subtitle_file_path and os.path.exists(subtitle_file_path):
                    os.remove(subtitle_file_path)

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            futures = [
                    executor.submit(convert_video_to_video, file, video_format, compression_percentage)
                    for file, video_format, compression_percentage in zip(files, video_formats, compression_percentages)
                ]


            for future in futures:
                try:
                    future.result()  # Ensure any exception is raised here
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error(f"Exception in thread: {e}")


        if len(download_links) > 1:
            zip_filename = 'converted_videos.zip'
            zip_path = os.path.join('/tmp', zip_filename)

            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w') as zipf:
                for link in download_links:
                    filename = os.path.basename(link)
                    zipf.write(filename, filename)

            s3.upload_file(
                zip_path,
                bucket_name,
                folder + zip_filename,
                ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'application/zip'}
            )

            zip_download_link = f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{folder + zip_filename}"
            download_links.append(zip_download_link)

        return Response({'status': 'Processing complete', 'download_links': download_links, 'success': success}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
